# C# text file read

Tags: c#, file

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog.FileName = "ok";
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Murat\Pictures\New folder\DE.TXT");
        string satir;
        int sayac=0;
        while((satir = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
            //listBox1.Items.Add(satir);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(satir + "\n");
            sayac++;
            }
        SR.Close();
```

OpenFileDialog.FileName is could not :( help please.

I want to enter a file path while reading data from a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading From a Text File in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980456/reading-from-a-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Don't you want OpenFileDialogFilename = "DE.TXT"?  You can set openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory.

Comment: yes but with openFileDialog

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing how to use the OpenFileDialog:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {             
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(OpenFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                string satir;
                while ((satir = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(satir + "\n");
                }
            }
            int sayac = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();
        }   
    }
```

Note that you could also just do:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {             
            richTextBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
            int sayac = richTextBox1.Lines.Count();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: openFileDialog does not have such a property either.

Comment: openFileDialog errormessage: an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property  commonDialog.showDialog

Comment: Does not have **what** property?  Your second error message indicates that you do not have an OpenFileDialog on your form.  Did you add one to your form?  Usually it would be called "openFileDialog1".