# Using what? What do I use to make a program that opens .obj and .dae using c#?

Tags: c#, file, file-format

I'm currently teaching myself computer programming I know a little but; would like to jump right in now that I know the correct structure.  But as far as the name space and the appmanifest.xml what is needed there?  And to open a .dae file what method or function do I use?  And I can create my own file type right, as like a special bookmark for my program to pick up where I left off, as in blender has .blend if I called my app simonsays or something I can have .simon file format right?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is asking. If you understand the structure of the files, what's stopping you?

Comment: I understand the format on how c# is organized, I understand that you have to add the correct namespace to beable to do certain things like open those types of files aka like 
using System;
using SystemIO; etc, thats where I need direction and I also need direction on basic commands to tell the app after a button is clicked lets say an open button that opens a 3dmodel .dae file and brings it up at your canvas, would I use a canvas?

Comment: I obviously need to read and study a lot more, but there are so many namespaces and there are so many ways to create a function but you still have to have it right down to the capiltle letter like ManipulationStartedEventHandler

Comment: what does a basic function look like to open a simple txt file?

Comment: The keyword you need for linking a file with your application is "file association". The first result I found for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application). You can find basic _text file_ reading code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980456/reading-from-a-text-file-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Ok wow, there is help from Directx and an Engine
[Creating an Interactive 3d world using engines and directx](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/graphics/article.php/c11375/Creating-an-Interactive-3D-World-in-CNET.htm)